# Button to Show More Posts on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to add a button on my home page to show more posts.  Currently, I have my posts_per_page set to 9.  I'd like to include a button that will add 3 more posts to the loop, but have had no luck finding how to do such a thing.

Please note, I do not want to use the button to redirect away from the home page, simply increase the posts_per_page by 3 each time the button is clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us your code :) don't wait for us to write it..

Comment: Use infinite scroll plugin if U need Ajax loading

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go: http://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-pagination

Used in the past and seemed to do the job!